# How to construct a k-regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a hard time to find a way to construct a `k`-regular graph out of `n` vertices. There seems to be a lot of theoretical material on regular graphs on the internet but I can't seem to extract construction rules for regular graphs.

My preconditions are

```
k<n and (n%2 == 0 or k%2 == 0)
```

Is an adjacency matrix the way to go here? If so, how would I use it?

Is this even a mathematical problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If $k=2m$ is even, put all the vertices around a circle, and join each to its $m$ nearest neighbors on either side.

If $k=2m+1$ is odd, and $n$ is even, put the vertices on a circle, join each to its $m$ nearest neighbors on each side, and also to the vertex directly opposite.

Comment: Note that for $k \gt 1$ the resulting $k$-regular graph is connected, because it contains the $n$-cycle solution given by $k=2$.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have an initial $k$-regular graph, you can generate many more by randomly applying the following simple switching operation:

[image: Switching operation illustration]

provided it does not introduce a parallel edge or loop.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished this question from Allen Downey's book Think Complexity, and thought I'll just share my algorithm (which is the same as Gerry's answer but just fleshed out) :

Preconditions: 0 < k and k < n

**If n is odd, k must be even

```
Number of Vertex (n) : Possible Number of degrees for each Vertex (k)
                  2  :  1
                  3  :  2
                  4  :  1,2,3
                  5  :  2,4
                  6  :  1,2,3,4,5
                  7  :  2,4,6
                  8  :  1,2,3,4,5,6,7
                  9  :  2,4,6,8
                 10  :  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Examples:

```
if n is 7:
    if k is 2:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)
    if k is 4:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(3)
    if k is 6:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(3)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(5)

if n is 8:
    if k is 1:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(4)
    if k is 2:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)
    if k is 3:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(4)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(3)
    if k is 4:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(2)
    if k is 5:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(4)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(3)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(2)
    if k is 6:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(2)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(3)
    if k is 7:
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(4)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(3)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(2)
        make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(1)

make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(x):
    for each vertice, adds an edge to a neighbor x steps away. 
    if x == 1, edges will be created between v1 and v2, v2 and v3,..., vn to v1
```

There is a pattern where

-If n is odd, we add edges between vertices x positions away, where x is all odd numbers between 1 to k.

-If n is even, and k is even, we add edges between vertices x positions away, where x is a range of numbers starting from 1 to n/2, and the range of these numbers is limited by the number of even numbers from 1 to k, including k

-If n is even, and k is odd, we add edges between vertices x positions away,
where x is a range of numbers starting from n/2 to 1, and the range of these numbers is limited by the number of odd numbers from 1 to k, including k

Algorithm:

```
Layout_all_vertices_in_a_circle()
if n is even:
    if k is even:
        countEvenNumbers = n/2
        #add an edge for each even number between 1 to k, including k
        for i in range(countEvenNumbers):
            make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(i+1)
    else if k is odd:
        countOddNumbers = ((n-1)/2) + 1
        #add an edge for each odd number between 1 to k, including 1 and k
        for i in range(countOddNumbers):
            make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away((n/2)-i)

if n is odd:
    for i in range(1, k):
        if i is odd:
            make_edge_for_each_vertice_x_steps_away(i)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cayley graphs. Take a group $G$ of order $n$ and a subset $S$ of order $k$ such that $S$ does not contain the identity and such that $s \in S$ if and only if $s^{-1} \in S$. Then the Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G,S)$ is the graph with vertices $G$ and $(g,h)$ is an edge if and only if $g=hs$ for some $s \in S$. This will always give a $k$-regular graph of order $n$. It is connected if and only if $S$ generates $G$.

Another way is to look at a graphical sequence and reduce it. Then you can trace back the reductions and construct such a graph. For example look at the sequence $3,3,3,3$, which means that there are $4$ vertices and each of them has degree $3$. One can reduce such a sequence by deleting the leading number, say $l$, and substract $1$ from the first $l$ of the remaining numbers. In our example we would delete $3$ and get $2,2,2$. After such operations one needs to sort the sequence in decending order. Now you can continue doing this until you have an easy seqence for which you can draw the graph. Our sequence $2,2,2$ represents the cycle graph of order 3. Finally we need to undo the reduction. Here we need to add a vertex of degree $3$. Here there is a unique way in doing so and we get the complete graph $K_4$, but in general reduing these steps is not unique(otherewise there would only be one $k$-regular graph of order $n$). If you look at every possible reduction and every possible way to undo the procedure, you can construct every possible $k$-regular graph of order $n$.