# Homework on Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I need your help to give simple proofs of the followings.

1. Show that there exists a $d$-regular graph with order $n$ iff $0 \leq d \leq n-1$ and at least one of the values $d, n$ is even.
2. Let A be the adjacency matrix of a d-regular graph G. Prove that d is an eigenvalue of A
   with multiplicity at least the number of connected components of G.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 check this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142112/how-to-construct-a-k-regular-graph?rq=1) As for 2 consider the vector with all coordinates equal to $1$.

Comment: Can you explain more exactly? I dont understand.

Comment: Did you check the link? As for 2, the vector of all ones is an eigenvector with eigenvalue d.

Comment: I understand 1. But not yet 2.

Comment: I undestood but your proof is true for connection of $G$. Which proof if $G$ has $k$-connected components? The problem still the second part on multiplicity of d that u did not prove.

Comment: For each component,  the vector containing $1$'s for coordinates corresponding to vertices in the component  is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $d$. You can easily prove that those vectors are linearly independent. That will prove the multiplicity part.