# How to detect whether the two graphs are topologically equivalent

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

From this link I construct a regular graph .[How to construct a k-regular graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142112/how-to-construct-a-k-regular-graph)

10-4 regular graph:

here is one m choose

```
def get_2mth_v(self,v:Vertex,m:int) -> List[Vertex]:
    """ m neibor on eachside"""
    answer = []

    if m == 0 :
        return answer

    v_index = self.vindex[v]
    vnum = len(self.vindex)

    for i in range(1,m+1) :
        answer.append(self.indexv[ (v_index-i) % vnum ])
        answer.append(self.indexv[ (v_index+i) % vnum ])


    return answer
```

graph1
[image: m 's step is 1]

the other one is

```
   def get_2mth_v(self,v:Vertex,m:int) -> List[Vertex]:
        """ m neibor on eachside"""
        answer = []

        if m == 0 :
            return answer

        v_index = self.vindex[v]
        vnum = len(self.vindex)

        for i in range(1,m+1) :
            answer.append(self.indexv[ (v_index-i*2) % vnum ])
            answer.append(self.indexv[ (v_index+i*2) % vnum ])
```

graph2
[image: m's step is 2]

So are these two graphs the same in some way? If they are the same, why?

---

update

as yes or not connectivity is clear to detect wheather it is equal 
may be this method need see more .

```
def get_2mth_v_stepii(self,v:Vertex,m:int) -> List[Vertex]:
    """ m neibor on eachside"""
    answer = []

    if m == 0 :
        return answer

    v_index = self.vindex[v]
    vnum = len(self.vindex)

    for i in range(1,m+1) :
        answer.append(self.indexv[ (v_index-i*i) % vnum ])
        answer.append(self.indexv[ (v_index+i*i) % vnum ])


    return answer
```

graph3
[image]

So graph1 and graph3 both is connected .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second graph is not connected (the first is) so is not topologically equivalent to the first graph in most senses of 'topologically equivalent'. They're not isomorphic as graphs, homeomorphic, homotopy equivalent, shape equivalent, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Two graphs $G_1, G_2$ are "the same" (more formally, *isomorphic*) when there's a bijection $\phi$ between their vertex sets such that $\phi(x)\phi(v)$ is an edge in $G_2$ if and only if $xy$ is an edge in $G_1$.

Do you need help applying this criterion to your example graphs or can you take it from there? (As Daniel Rust points out, one graph is not connected, and the other is, so there can't be such a bijection, but if you can't immediately see that I can try to help.)

Comment: yes you can . may be more Formal definition can help to implement is_two_graph_same() fun.